# Destroy ALL .draggable in a DIV jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'd like to destroy all .draggable(s) in a div after one of the draggables from this DIV is dropped.

In the droppable i wrote a function to try and handle this but it seems to kill the page.

```
var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
var parentDiv = $( "#"+draggableId ).parent();
$('#'+parentDiv+'.draggable').draggable("destroy");
```

The last line I'm trying to select and destroy all elements with a class of draggable in the parent div and destroy them. This, however, seems to not work.

Is there an easy way to destroy all jquery-ui draggables in a specified DIV? Below is the more full function i call when a droppable receives a draggable.

```
function handleCardDrop(event, ui) {

        var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
        var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");

        var parentDiv = $( "#"+draggableId ).parent();
        $( "#"+draggableId ).removeAttr( "id" );
        $(this).droppable('disable');
        var objectClone = $(ui.draggable).clone();
        $(objectClone).attr("id",draggableId);
        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false); 

        $(objectClone).draggable({
            cursor: 'move',
            helper: 'clone',
            revert: true
        });

        $(this).append($(objectClone));

        //$(parentDiv + " > div").draggable( "destroy" );
        $('#'+parentDiv+'.draggable').draggable("destroy");
    }
```

**EDIT**
Below is a codePen of my problem. The draggables are not destroyed after the drop. You can still drag them. Maybe I am not targeting them correctly?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBpJZp

Comment: Why not: `parentDiv.find('.draggable').draggable("destroy");` ?!

Comment: Part of my issue is that I did not have the correct ID of the parent: var parentDiv = $( "#"+draggableId ).parent().attr("id");

Comment: So, if you have found a solution then either answer it or....

Comment: I haven't found a solution. This is my simplified problem. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBpJZp. I cannot destroy the draggables. Have tried a bunch of different ways to do it. Am not having any luck.